# Robot Thinks It's Stuck When It Isn't

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've got an annoying problem here. I've trying to get the robot to un-dock from the charging station, navigate then come back.

In the screen-shot below you can see that there is free space round the robot, but in the planning output it wants to start recover procedures when there is no need. All it needs to do it reverse out (I've already set min_vel_x: -1.0 to achieve this). Still no luck. What else can I try tuning? I can't see anything else in dwa_local_planner_params.yaml, costmap_common_params.yaml, local_costmap_params.yaml or global_costmap_params.yaml which looks immediately obvious.

[image: image description]

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282375/robot-thinks-it%27s-stuck-when-it-isn%27t/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2018-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-02-13**:
Please provide more information about what planner you are using and what messages you're getting when things won't work.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2018-02-13**:
I'm using the DWA planner (sorry thought I'd added that). The error message is "Rotate recovery can't rotate in place because there is a potential collision. Cost -1.0"

Which is odd because, as you can see in the screen shot there is a path that has been calculated (in the direction I would expect

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2018-02-18**:
What do you mean by visualizing the local footprint?

Thanks

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-02-18**:
There should be a Polygon topic that is something like `.../whatever/local_costmap/footprint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try visualizing the robot's (local) footprint.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0